# Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error (my first SPA app)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm writing an SPA app in Angular for the first time but have come across a problem.

My JavaScript to create the route looks like this:

```
$(function() {
    angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"])
        .config(function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.otherwise({
                templateUrl: "/angular/components/booking-system/booking-system-template.html"
            });
        });
});
```

and my 'master page' (what's the correct terminology?) looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>My App</title>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/angular/scripts/route-config.js"></script>
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container body-content">
        <ng-view/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$injector/nomod?p0=ibo...
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:4685/Scripts/angular.min.js:6:417
    at http://localhost:4685/Scripts/angular.min.js:21:412
    at a (http://localhost:4685/Scripts/angular.min.js:21:53)
    at http://localhost:4685/Scripts/angular.min.js:21:296
    at http://localhost:4685/Scripts/angular.min.js:35:116
    at s (http://localhost:4685/Scripts/angular.min.js:7:302)
    at g (http://localhost:4685/Scripts/angular.min.js:34:399)
    at ab (http://localhost:4685/Scripts/angular.min.js:38:135)
    at d (http://localhost:4685/Scripts/angular.min.js:17:381
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help!

M

Comment: whats the module called `ibosApp ` ?

Comment: Sorry, that should read myApp. Edited.

Comment: @serlingpa - Where do you include your app.js file?

Comment: I don't have an app.js file. Yet! At the moment I'm just trying to get the first view to render.

Comment: In your error message, `injector/nomod?p0=ibo..` it's not related to current code. Could you please share more code? p0=ibo points to some other dependency error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like your having problem with the self executing block because of the `$` sign  change the code like below and try,

```
(function(){
    angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"])
    .config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.otherwise({
            templateUrl: "/angular/components/booking-system/booking-system-template.html"
        });
    });
}());
```

Comment: I got excited there for a moment, but unfortunately that didn't work. Throws the same exception.

Comment: I do't think it's the cause. because the OP has added jquery file as well. So it doesn't matter. But yes, need not include angularjs code inside document.ready because angular will bootstrap in domcontentloaded event only